# How to write a Validator Pattern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

I was wondering how to build a Ruby on Rails design for replacing a switch/case.

```
switch (needle) {
        case 'hello' :
            // some operation
            return "something"
            break;

        case 'world' :
            // some operation
            return "something"
            break;

        default :
            return "default";
            break;
    }
```

I am thinking of different classes representing the validators. Is there a pattern for this?

```
class hello
  def validate
    // validate something
  end
 def execute
    // do something
  end
end

class world
  def validate
    // validate something
  end
 def execute
    // do something
  end
end

class implementation
  def main
    validate(hello, world)
  end
end
```

Comment: A little more information on what you are trying to do exactly would help

Comment: I just want to check different things with strings. E.g. with indexOf()

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom validation classes in Rails. See http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/07/29/rails-model-validators/

Then you just use them in your models.

There's also the underused pattern:

```
# string with square brackets and a regexp, returning the first match or nil
"fred"[/d/]
```

You can have some fun with this pulling things out of strings and using them as messages, but be warned debugging this kind of thing can be a nightmare.

Are you really just trying to send an arbitrary message to an object? In which case `send()` will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

you may do something like:

```
class MyClass
  def my_method my_valitation_str
    validator = Validator.from_str validation_str
    validator.validate
  end

  class Validator
    class Hello
      def self.str
        "hello"
      end
      def validate
         ... the hello validation code
      end
    end
    class World
      def self.str
        "world"
      end
      def validate
         ... the hello validation code
      end
    end
    def self.validator_types
      [Hello, World]
    end

    def self.from_str val_str
      validator_types.select{|t| t.str == val_str}.first
    end
  end
end
```

Using nested classes is totaly optional.

But in most cases you wouldn't need to use classes.. The Validator Class could be a module. and from_str could return modules directly.

Actually, if "validate" is meant to operate on a MyClass instance, than you could extend the class with the returned module...